# TCP/IP connection on slider

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uislider, tcp

I am trying to  send data using TCP/ip conection on slider change value but connection fail Event directly call NSStreamEventErrorOccuer: I am using below Link for connection.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server

Answer (score 0):

Probably your socket is not open, e.g. you have no TCP connection.

On the page you linked is no TCP connection associated with slider change. So it is difficult to give more specific help.

Best, Peter.